# PHP: Add quotes before and after every parentheses

Tags: php, regex, string

I have this string:

> $str = "Subscriber (TG)(times), Subscriber Service (TG)(times)"

I'd like to add single quotes before and after every parentheses so now it looks like this:

```
$str = "Subscriber `(TG)``(times)`, Subscriber Service `(TG)``(times)`"
```

How can I accomplish this in PHP? Maybe with regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://php.net/str_replace. Your example is wildly inconsistent. why does the first TG/Times get )``( and the other TG/Times doesn't?

Comment: @p.s.w.g My mistake :( Updated now

Comment: @p.s.w.g I don't know how to accomplish it, I readed somewhere I should use $str = preg_replace("","`",$str); But I don't really know how

Comment: regexes are massive overkill for such a simple change. use string replacement

Comment: @MarcB My mistake, it's updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `str_replace`, works like this:

```
$str = str_replace("(", "'(", $str);
$str = str_replace(")", ")'", $str);
```

Comment: $str = str_replace(array("(",")"), array("'(","')"), $str);

Answer (score 1):

You can use lookarounds:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(?<=\))|(?=\()~', '`', $str);
```

or a simple string replacement:

```
$arr = array('(' => '`(', ')' => ')`');
$str = strtr($str, $arr);
```

*(which is probably the fastest way)*

If you want to deal with nested parenthesis:

```
$str = preg_replace('~\((?>[^()]++|(?R))*\)~', '`$0`', $str);
```

Comment: Nice solution! I'd just like to draw attention to cases of parentheses within parentheses something like "Subscriber ( (TG) (times) )", but it cannot be solved by regex.

Answer (score 1):

```
$str =str_replace('(','`(',$str);
$str =str_replace(')',')`',$str);
```

add this code  after `$str` it's ok!

Answer (score 1):

Don't overuse regex, a simple string replace on every '(' char and ')' char will be enough:

```
$str = str_replace('(', '`(', $str);
$str = str_replace(')', ')`', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your String, you can create a tiny function.

```
$str = "Subscriber `(TG)``(times)`, Subscriber Service `(TG)``(times)`";
print put($str);

function put($mystring)
{
   $firstRep = str_replace("(", "'('", $mystring);
   $secondRep =  str_replace(")", "')'", $firstRep);

   return $secondRep;
}
```

hope it helps